# Location of Windows Phone 8 files that are marked as content

Tags: c#, c++, file-io, windows-phone-8

I'm creating Windows Phone 8 Direct3D application with XAML (C++).
I have to process several files in my C++ code before I can use them. These files are added to the Component project and marked as content.
After I processed them, I want to use them from my XAML C# application.

What path should I use to access these files?
It seems that

```
ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder
```

doesn't contain any of them.

Or what conception should I use in my application to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those items will be in `Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation` but you should copy files to `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` on first launch.

Comment: Why should you copy the files to that location?